# do I have to flush a cache to enable my javascript mixin

Tags: magento2, mixins

I did create a mixins this morning for the checkout (shipping address exactly)

Whilst it has been some time since I have not added a mixins, it is a fairly standard feature in magento frontend customisation. Yet, after clearing cache, browser cache and trying to see my mixins, I cannot succeed to load the mixin as expected

Is there a way to reliable ensure a new javascript mixins can be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I have now worked out a solution to my issue.

I have ran `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and that does seem to make my mixin appearing. Hope this may help somebody to get his/her mixin working faster.